# mount: mount point none does not exist

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I am having problems trying to mount a swap file for use.
Every time I use this command to mount (with /var/swap being the file):

```
$ sudo mount /var/swap
```

I keep getting this message:

```
mount: mount point none does not exist
```

This is the swap entry in my /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=84c3776d-3f52-4b86-b0c6-4f5c2c776d94  none  swap  sw  0   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap isn't mounted like a filesystem, you need to use [`swapon`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html):

```
swapon -a
```

will use all the swap defined in `/etc/fstab`.

You can specify a specific file or partition to add instead:

```
swapon swapfile
```

will add the swap file `swapfile`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stephen, I will just add the command to my startup script.

Comment: If swap is listed in your fstab you shouldn't need to add a "swapon" command to get it working. If you just type "swapon" (no options), it should show you your current swap partition(s), if any.

Comment: Yes, in the same way as other partitions, anything present in `/etc/fstab` is used at boot; running `swapon` is only useful if you add swap to `/etc/fstab` without rebooting.

Comment: Actually I could not get it to mount at boot either.